# C# Windows service - Out of memory error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, memory

I have written a service that processes tif files.
Part of the process is to split a multi page tif into single pages.

I get an out of memory error on the following line :

```
System.Drawing.Image tiffImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
```

The service is running on a server that is underutilised and has lots of memory available.

I did some research and people say that the error may occur if the tif is incorrect (something to do with pixal format).
However i run the code on my desktop (debug) with the same tif file and it splits no problem.

When i use the following code to find memory usage :

```
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

> Message :- "Memory Usage" + proc.PrivateMemorySize64

```
I get the following results :  
12mb - server  
27mb - desktop
```

Does this mean that the service on the server has been allocated less memory ?
Or does it mean the service on the server is using less memory ?

Any help would be fantastic
Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing is implemenented by gdiplus.dll. May be different versions of it are running on two machines.

Try to switch to WPF imaging API in System.Windows.Media.Imaging.

Comment: i tried using WPF imaging but i get an error when it runs on the server (not when i use it on my dev PC). the error is "Property cannot be found" it appears when i use  BitmapDecoder.Create(originalFile, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None); Have you any ideas ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try NOT to use anything microsoft on imaging. If your service just splits tiff files, I recommend you to use libtiff with interop calls or command line.

MS and many other graphics toolkits try to load images. With libtiff, you don't have to load it, and you can inspect headers before splitting.

Downside is, it is hard to use it.

BTW: In 2003, for a performance test for our ICR engine, we compiled libtiff using Intel C++ Compiler. Loaded a A3, 400 dpi 24 bit color tiff file and converted it to black and white using a simple threshold algorithm. It all took 200~ ms in a 1300 Mhz Intel Xeon CPU with 1 GB of memory. this may give you some numbers

Comment: Do you have a basic example using Libtiff ? Just to et me started ? the ones online a confusing me a little.

Comment: try this file https://www.box.com/s/n2b8yks3kwhb72z2f1dd . I hack ported official tiffsplit of libtiff to c#. never tested, It may not even work, probably will not. but it is a good starting point for you